# Removing @JvmSuppressWildcards not working android dagger 2.25.2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have updated my dagger with `2.25.2` and as per the latest release we don't need `@JvmSuppressWildcards` this annotation anymore. I remove it and trying to run the app but its not working showing dagger build error like:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Set<? extends com.test.deeplinking.handlers.DeeplinkHandler> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

My dagger module:

```
@Module
abstract class DeeplinkHandlerSetModule {

    @Multibinds
    abstract fun deeplinkHandlers(): Set<DeeplinkHandler>

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideEntryDeeplinkHandler(
        set: Set<DeeplinkHandler>, .., ..
    ) = EntryDeeplinkHandler(set, ..., ...)

}
```

Adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` like `set: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards DeeplinkHandler>` working fine. Even does it support from dagger 2.25.2 version? Anyone can confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `@JvmSuppressWildcards` is not needed anymore?
In the release notes there isn't anything related with it, as far as I can tell.
https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

The only similar item is not needing `@JvmStatic` on module objects.

Comment: I suspect that was a mistake from the author